# Nodejs: Cannot find module npmlog

Tags: node.js, nodes

i'm trying to install gulp but it's showing Error:
current version :v4.3.1

```
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:20:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:76:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm` is the path for global installed modules, so if I have to guess, your global installed npm is not up to date. Try to remove the global installed npm and use the built in version, that comes with the node installer. To remove the global installed npm delete the `npm` and `npm.cmd` files in `C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm` and the folder npm in `C:\Users\achraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`.